# making faces from line art

Tags: 2d, lineart

"Add line art to object" with contour and intersection strokes makes a wonderful outline of my complex mesh (lines are generated line art, colors are the mesh with a simple emissive material applied). [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fzq4.png) What I'd like to have is a way to project a face onto a plane bounded by each set of black lines so that I could assign them different materials or heights for, e.g., a stained glass or inlaid wood effect.
What I've tried:

1. Applying line art modifier, re-projecting the grease pencil strokes, converting grease pencil to polygon mesh and then knife projecting onto a plane. The projection takes an extremely long time to complete, and the results are hit-and-miss, with a few regions looking OK and others missing lots of edges. Making coherent faces is pretty much impossible.
2. A DIY approach using geometry nodes to create a flat cutter mesh from the original mesh. I was able to simplify the geometry a ton so that mostly outlines of the original atoms and bonds remained, but this was still apparently too complex for the knife project method.
3. Exporting to SVG and cleaning up somehow. I feel like there should be a utility out there that basically takes a "paint can tool" approach to remapping strokes, but I have no idea where one would find this.

Is there any sensible workflow for achieving this result? I'm open to using add-ons or even non-Blender SVG editing software if that's the answer.